# Sonar Error Logs while restarting Sonar

Tags: java, mysql, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Below are the error logs observed when I am restarting the Sonar.

Versions used-

MySql-

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.55, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

Java-

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Sonar-

```
Version 5.1.1 - LGPL v3 - Community - Documentation - Get Support - Plugins - Web Service API
```

My Sonar.properties file-

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
sonar.web.port=9000
```

Also I have added my IP under /ets/hosts.Please suggest why is the cause of the error logs.

```
TERM trapped.  Shutting down.
2017.06.15 06:03:45 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[web] is stopping
2017.06.15 06:03:46 INFO  web[o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process
2017.06.15 06:03:46 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9080"]
2017.06.15 06:03:46 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service stopped
2017.06.15 06:03:46 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
2017.06.15 06:03:46 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9080"]
2017.06.15 06:03:47 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9080"]
2017.06.15 06:03:47 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
2017.06.15 06:03:47 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[web] is stopped
2017.06.15 06:03:47 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
2017.06.15 06:03:47 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2017.06.15 06:03:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1497506533409] stopping ...
2017.06.15 06:03:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1497506533409] stopped
2017.06.15 06:03:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1497506533409] closing ...
2017.06.15 06:03:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1497506533409] closed
2017.06.15 06:03:47 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017.06.15 06:03:52 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process5953723730418892518properties
2017.06.15 06:03:53 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2017.06.15 06:03:53 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
2017.06.15 06:03:53 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1497506632689] version[1.4.4], pid[2762], build[c88f77f/2015-02-19T13:05:36Z]
2017.06.15 06:03:53 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1497506632689] initializing ...
2017.06.15 06:03:53 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1497506632689] loaded [], sites []
2017.06.15 06:03:54 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1497506632689] initialized
2017.06.15 06:03:54 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1497506632689] starting ...
2017.06.15 06:03:54 WARN   es[o.e.common.network]  failed to resolve local host, fallback to loopback
java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-10-1-144: ip-10-10-1-144: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkUtils.<clinit>(NetworkUtils.java:55) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.createClientBootstrap(NettyTransport.java:350) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:250) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:91) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.start(InternalNode.java:242) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.start(SearchServer.java:46) [sonar-search-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:77) [sonar-process-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.main(SearchServer.java:80) [sonar-search-5.1.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-10-1-144: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
2017.06.15 06:03:54 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1497506632689] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/10.10.1.144:9001]}
2017.06.15 06:03:55 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1497506632689] sonarqube/Q6auH-7JTS2lEBIKDkZ0bQ
2017.06.15 06:03:58 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1497506632689] new_master [sonar-1497506632689][Q6auH-7JTS2lEBIKDkZ0bQ][localhost][inet[/10.10.1.144:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1497506632689}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2017.06.15 06:03:58 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1497506632689] started
2017.06.15 06:03:58 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1497506632689] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
2017.06.15 06:04:00 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
2017.06.15 06:04:00 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process611872039216276506properties
2017.06.15 06:04:00 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2017.06.15 06:04:00 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp] Webapp directory: /opt/sonar/web
2017.06.15 06:04:01 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2017.06.15 06:04:01 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2017.06.15 06:04:01 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1497506632689] loaded [], sites []
2017.06.15 06:04:01 WARN  web[o.e.common.network] failed to resolve local host, fallback to loopback
java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-10-1-144: ip-10-10-1-144: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkUtils.<clinit>(NetworkUtils.java:55) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.createClientBootstrap(NettyTransport.java:350) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:250) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:91) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:189) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:123) [elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.search.SearchClient.<init>(SearchClient.java:75) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:631) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:631) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1033) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1025) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91) [sonar-plugin-api-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel1Container(Platform.java:96) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:72) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-10-1-144: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        ... 63 common frames omitted
2017.06.15 06:04:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.1.1 / 0a231d24c0f1e7ce1d200274b8e9bbe00f9f49fb
2017.06.15 06:04:02 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.Database] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
2017.06.15 06:04:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: /opt/sonar
2017.06.15 06:04:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Install plugins
2017.06.15 06:04:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Core / 5.1.1 / 0a231d24c0f1e7ce1d200274b8e9bbe00f9f49fb
2017.06.15 06:04:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Email notifications / 5.1.1 / 0a231d24c0f1e7ce1d200274b8e9bbe00f9f49fb
2017.06.15 06:04:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Java / 3.0 / 65396a609ddface8b311a6a665aca92a7da694f1
2017.06.15 06:04:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Git / 1.0 / 9ce9d330c313c296fab051317cc5ad4b26319e07
2017.06.15 06:04:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin English Pack / 5.1.1 / 0a231d24c0f1e7ce1d200274b8e9bbe00f9f49fb
2017.06.15 06:04:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.0 / 213fc8a8b582ff530b12dd4a59a6512be1071234
2017.06.15 06:04:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
2017.06.15 06:04:03 INFO  web[o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector] Initializing Hibernate
2017.06.15 06:04:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2017.06.15 06:04:05 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2017.06.15 06:04:05 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index rules
2017.06.15 06:04:06 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index activeRules
2017.06.15 06:04:06 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2017.06.15 06:04:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Cleaning quality gate conditions
2017.06.15 06:04:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDebtModel] Register technical debt model
2017.06.15 06:04:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2017.06.15 06:04:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
2017.06.15 06:04:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters] Register measure filters
2017.06.15 06:04:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards] Register dashboards
2017.06.15 06:04:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
2017.06.15 06:04:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
2017.06.15 06:04:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index activities
2017.06.15 06:04:08 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index issues
2017.06.15 06:04:08 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index source lines
2017.06.15 06:04:08 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index users
2017.06.15 06:04:08 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index views
2017.06.15 06:04:08 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_131-b11 [linux-amd64]
2017.06.15 06:04:08 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2017.06.15 06:04:14 INFO  web[jruby.rack] keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
2017.06.15 06:04:14 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2017.06.15 06:04:14 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2017.06.15 06:04:14 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2017.06.15 06:04:15 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
```

Answer (score 1):

About your errors, you can safely ignore this error during the stop :

```
 2017.06.15 06:03:46 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
```

About the second error :

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-10-1-144: ip-10-10-1-144: Name or service not known
```

I suspect that the name of the machine (ip-10-10-1-144) is not defined in `/etc/hosts` (according to your description of mysql you are using Debian)

So adding the following snippet to `/etc/hosts`should fix the issue :

```
127.0.1.1    ip-10-10-1-144
```

Comment: I have already added "127.0.1.1 ip-10-10-1-144" snippet in my /etc/hosts file. Still its the same